# Azure Blob Storage: Download all logs from Azure Storage Container "$logs" using C#

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download all the logs from the Container "**$logs**", but it always throws a Exception -

**"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\logs\blob\2020\05\24\2300\000000.log'"**

```
public static void GetAnalyticsLogs(CloudBlobClient blobClient, CloudTableClient tableClient)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        CloudAnalyticsClient analyticsClient = new CloudAnalyticsClient(blobClient.StorageUri, tableClient.StorageUri, tableClient.Credentials);
        IEnumerable<ICloudBlob> results = analyticsClient.ListLogs(StorageService.Blob, time.AddDays(-30), null, LoggingOperations.All, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, null, null);
        List<ICloudBlob> logs = results.ToList();
        foreach (var item in logs)
        {
            string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)item).Name;
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("$logs");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);
            string path = (@"C:/logs/" + name);
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
            {
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

How can we solve this error?

Comment: Hi, what is `CloudAnalyticsClient`? it's a custom class or any packages you're using?

Comment: Please check it here its not Custom class: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Analytics/CloudAnalyticsClient.cs

Comment: why not use the latest version sdk: [Blob Storage SDK v12 for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs).

Comment: Yeah I can do that also but still the problem will remain same right?

Comment: Please check the answer below:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the path contains directories, but the File.Create() method cannot create a file inside a directory if the directory does not exist. So you should create the directory first, then create the file using File.Create() method.

The code below works fine at my side:

```
public static void GetAnalyticsLogs(CloudBlobClient blobClient, CloudTableClient tableClient)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.UtcNow;
        CloudAnalyticsClient analyticsClient = new CloudAnalyticsClient(blobClient.StorageUri, tableClient.StorageUri, tableClient.Credentials);
        IEnumerable<ICloudBlob> results = analyticsClient.ListLogs(StorageService.Blob, time.AddDays(-30), null, LoggingOperations.All, BlobListingDetails.Metadata, null, null);
        List<ICloudBlob> logs = results.ToList();
        foreach (var item in logs)
        {
            string name = ((CloudBlockBlob)item).Name;
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("$logs");
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(name);

            //specify the directory without file name
            string sub_folder = name.Remove(name.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);                   
            string path = (@"C:/logs/" + sub_folder);

            //create the directory if it does not exist.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            //specify the file full path
            string file_path= (@"C:/logs/" + name);

            using (var fileStream = File.Create(file_path))
            {
                
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```